# No Textbox can take the focus by mouse clicking in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, gwt

I have a problem in GWT 2.0.4 that I can reproduce only with IE8
(Windows XP). I use a TabPanel with IFrames in the tabs. When I close
a tab which has an element with focus no TextBox in other tabs can
take the focus by mouse clicking (but only by Tab-Key). If the closed
tab did not have a focused element the problem does not occur. I tried
to use TabLayoutPanel but it did not help. What can cause such
behavior in the web browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to `blur()` or (`setFocused(false)`) the corresponding iframe when closing the tab.

Answer (score -1):

Just add style to Textbox:

`position:relative;`